# Why I get the Redux mutation Error and how can I avoid it?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using moment for some date utilities and I am storing the data in redux. After filling the form, searching the backend for the data, I get this error but I get it only the first time I search:

```
Error: Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path 'app.departureDate._locale._longDateFormat.ll'.  This may cause incorrect behavior.
```

This is the reducer:

```
addDepartureDate(state, action) {
   return { ...state, departureDate: action.payload };
}
```

And here I use the data:

```
const {
    flightType, 
    localeConfig,
    departure,
    arrival,
    departureDate,
    arrivalDate,
    currency
} = useSelector(state => state.app);
const startDate = departureDate;
```

And the value is changed only when a new date is selected from react-dates but the error is not thrown then, I get the error after trying to get data from the backend.

Comment: What is the actual data type being stored in that state path?  Is it a `moment` instance?

Comment: yes, is a moment object, but is initialized as an empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `moment` instance is both mutable and not serializable, and thus shouldn't be kept in the Redux store:

- https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-mutate-state
- https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#reducers-must-not-have-side-effects

Prefer keeping date values in the store as numeric timestamps or strings (ie, `date.toISOString()`, etc)